# PYTHON: Trying to create a vocabulary/translation quiz (Beginner)

Tags: python

I'm new to Python (and also to stackoverflow, as you will easily notice it !)

I'm actually trying to write a program that would work as follow :
the user launch the program.
he's being asked whether he wants to enter a new word, and the translation of that word.
The word and its translation are stored in a file (data.txt).
When he's done adding new words, the quiz starts.
The program pick a word, and ask the user for the translation. If the answer is similar to the translation in the file, the program returns "Great !", if not, it prints the correct answer.

As you can see, it's pretty simple. My problem here is working with the file, especially retrieving what is inside the file and using it correctly.

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*

#Vocabulary/translation quiz

import os
import random

keep_adding=input("Would you like to add a new word ? If yes, press \"O\" : ")
while keep_adding=="O":
    entry=[]
    word=input("Enter a word : ")
    word=str(word)
    entry.append(word)
    translation=input("And its translation : ")
    translation=str(translation)
    entry.append(translation)
    entry=str(entry)
    f = open("data.txt","a")
    f.write(entry)
    f.close()
    keep_adding=input("To continue, press \"O\" : ")

f = open("data.txt","a") #in case the file doesn't exist, we create one
f.close()

os.system('clear')
print("* * * QUIZ STARTS ! * * *")

f = open("data.txt","r")

text = f.readlines()
text = list(text)
print("What is the translation for : ",text[0], "?")
answer = input("Answer : ")
if (answer == text[1]):
    print("Congratulations ! That's the good answer !")
else:
    print("Wrong. The correct answer was : ",text[1])
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

**EDIT :** did bring some corrections to my code.
What I get is the following :

```
    * * * QUIZ STARTS ! * * *
What is the translation for :  ['alpha', 'bravo']['one', 'two']['x', 'y'] ?
Answer : alpha
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python_progs/voc.py", line 43, in <module>
    if (answer == text[1]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and in my file, I have this :

```
['alpha', 'bravo']['one', 'two']['x', 'y']
```

So actually, I would like to get only the first word in the question (i.e. alpha) and when answering bravo, having it right.

Comment: Is there a question here? Are you getting an error you don't understand? Is it not doing something you are expecting it to do? Please be specific.

Comment: What is your question? If your code works, and you're just asking for general advice, SO is the wrong place for it. I'd suggest: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah. Welcome to SO. Here are a few guidelines for asking questions: 1) Be specific. State *exactly* what you're problem is. What is your expected output? What is your input? If you have an error message, post the traceback *exactly* as it appears. 2) Try to isolate the code that is giving you a problem, if you can, post ONLY that portion in your question. 3) State the steps that you have taken to fix your problem. 4) Make sure that you *edit your question* with corrections. Just posting them in the comments makes them harder for others to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

You're main issue is the way you're storing/retrieving things in the quiz file.

You're doing `f.write(str(entry))`, which is writing the string representation of the entry. I'm not quite sure what your intent is here, but you should realize two things: 1) `str` representations of lists are tricky to turn back into lists (when reading the file) and 2) `write()` doesn't append newlines at the end. If you were to do:

```
f.write("line1")
f.write("line2")
f.write("line3")
```

Then your file would look like this:

```
line1line2line3
```

Anyway, everything is saved on one line, so when you do `f.readlines()`, this returns an object like so:

```
["['alpha', 'bravo']['one', 'two']['x', 'y']"]
```

Or more generally:

```
[a_string,]
```

As you can see, it's a list with only one item in it. That's why you get an error when you do

```
if (answer == text[1]):
```

You're trying to access a second item that doesn't exist.

#### The solution?

What you need to do is store each quiz/answer pair as a separate line, with a specific delimiter separating the quiz and answer:

```
    quiz, answer
    alpha, bravo
    one, two
    etc...
```

For example:

```
with open("myquizfile.txt", "w") as f:
    while keepGoing: #You'd have to add your own exit logic.
        question = input("Enter a question: ")
        answer = input("Enter an answer: ")
        f.write("{0},{1}\n".format(question, answer)) #Notice the newline, \n
```

And to read this file, you'd do something like this:

```
with open("myquizfile.txt", "r") as f:
    question_answer_pairs = [line.split(",") for line in f]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel !
Works perfectly fine ! I have to say I wasn't really used to some syntax, but it's time to learn :) So thanks again, the answer is even really easy to understand !

Comment: @bl1nk: No problem. I was afraid that some of the syntax would be a little tricky, but I'm glad my answer helped. The `with open() as f:` idiom is the recommended way to open a file. Once you exit the `with` block, the file automatically closes (no need to call `f.close()`) As for the other things, look up *list comprehensions*, and *string formatting*.

Comment: Thanks for your advices Joel and for the tips :)

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively do this; this requires no external files:)

```
###   WORDLIST   ###
list   = ['castigate','brave','prowess','tenacious','pre-emptive','orthodox','arcane','corpuscle','putrid','infidel','stratagem','affinity','abnegate','infraction']
mean   = ['to scold','courageous','skill','stubborn','early','traditional','mysterious','a living cell','rotting','unbeliever','scheme','attraction','to renounce','violation of law']
list1 = list.copy()

mean1 = mean.copy()
mean2 = mean.copy()
mean3 = mean.copy()
mean4 = mean.copy()

from random import randint
import random

word_count = len(list) - 1
options = []

options = random.sample(range(1, word_count), 4)

options1 = options.copy()
options2 = options.copy()
options3 = options.copy()
options4 = options.copy()
opt1 = options1.pop(0)
opt2 = options2.pop(1)
opt3 = options3.pop(2)
opt4 = options4.pop(3)

x = randint(0,3)
y = options.pop(x)
#ignore [options]
question = list.pop(y)
answer = mean.pop(y)

print("What is the meaning of",question,"?")
print("1)",mean1.pop(opt1))
print("2)",mean2.pop(opt2))
print("3)",mean3.pop(opt3))
print("4)",mean4.pop(opt4))

while True:
    try:
        userans = int(input("\nYour answer: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't get that.")
        continue
    else:
        break

if userans - 1 is x:
    print("Your answer is correct!")
else:
    if userans is 100:
        print("There are %s words in your personal dictionary" % word_count)
    else:
        if userans > 4:
            print("It's OK if you do not know the answer. Better luck next time:)\nThe meaning of %s is %s!" % (question, answer))
        else:
            print("Your answer is wrong!\nThe meaning of %s is %s!" % (question, answer))
```

Basically, this code contains two main lists containing words and meanings.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone would be interested in the program, here is my final code (and thanks again Joel Cornett for your help) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
# -*-coding:Utf-8 -*

#Vocabulary/translation quiz

import os
import random

keep_adding=input("Would you like to add a new word ? If yes, press \"O\" : ")
with open("data.txt","a") as f:
    while keep_adding=="O":
        word=input("Enter a word : ")
        translation=input("And its translation : ") 
        f.write("{0},{1},\n".format(word,translation))
        keep_adding=input("To continue, press \"O\" : ")


#in case the file doesn't exist, we create one :
with open("data.txt","a") as f:
    pass

os.system('clear')
print("* * * QUIZ STARTS ! * * *")

with open("data.txt","r") as f:
    question = [line.split(",") for line in f]
    i = 0
    score = 0
    while i<len(question):
        num = random.randint(0,len(question)-1)
        print("\nQuestion number ",i+1,": \nWhat is the translation for ", question[num][0], "?")
        answer = input("Answer : ")
        if (answer == str(question[num][1])):
            print("Congratulations ! That's the good answer !")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Wrong. The correct answer was : ",question[num][1])
        i += 1

if len(question)==0:
    print("\nThe file is empty. Please add new words to start the quiz !\n")
else:   
    if i>1:
        qu_pl = "questions"
    else:
        qu_pl = "question"
    if score>1:
        sc_pl = "answers"
    else:
        sc_pl = "answer"
    print("\n RESULTS :\n ",i, qu_pl,", ",score,"correct ",sc_pl," \n"\
    ," --> Your score is : ",score*100/i,"% !\n")
```